# Eclipse/Flex WTP Project Stops Working within Eclipse

Tags: apache-flex, eclipse, blazeds, eclipse-wtp

I have a Flex/WTP project within Eclipse that was running within Eclipse for a short time but then all of a sudden stopped working.  Specifically, it was complaining about not being able to find a Java class on the server-side.  I have not made any configuration or path changes to the project.

The specific error is:
 [FaultEvent fault=[RPC Fault faultString="Cannot create class of type 'com.company.project.business.LoginService'." faultCode="Server.ResourceUnavailable" faultDetail="Type

But, the problem actually looks like the classes are never being published to the temp version of tomcat that Eclipse sets up for the WTP project.

Has anyone seen this case where the Eclipse/Flex/WTP project stops publishing portions of the application.

NOTE:  If I export the WAR file from the project and run it on Tomcat myself, it works fine.

Any help would greatly be appreciated.

-FortPointUIGuy